# Where can I get a complete pom file for a Spring 5 web application?

Tags: spring, pom.xml, spring5

I am trying to move a Spring 4 app to Spring 5.  Where can I get a clear pom.xml for a basic Spring 5 web app, with ALL the dependencies in it, with versions?

Comment: @M.Deinum if I could look at a working Spring 5 pom, I could do that.  So where dso I find one?  Are there NO open source apps using Spring 5?

Comment: @M.Deinum I already tried that, and it didn't work.  if it did work, I never woudl have posted this in the first place. So is the answer that there simply does not exist an open source Spring 5 app where I can look at the pom.xml file? And no one has a working pom.xml they can upload?